# Pass text with special characters as get parameter in php

Tags: php, javascript

I want to pass any text as a get parameter to a php script. For know I just append the text this way:

```
action.php?text=Hello+my+name+is+bob
```

This url is composed by javascript and I do a ajax request with this url.

In action.php I do

```
$encoded = array_map('rawurlencode', $_GET);
```

But this does not work for special chars like `ÖÄüä`.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

url_encode(string) will return the given string with special characters converted into %XX format.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

I know you can send special characters fine without encoding through $_POST, which is another alternative

Answer (score 2):

try with url_encode().........