# PHP Script: How to pass special character strings as parameters to PHP script?

Tags: php, get, special-characters

I created a PHP script for MySQL operations.

For operations with input parameters in most cases the PHP Script gets a String with special characters, like:

```
33e3#f&0BOAA34&%
```

I call the script from the app attaching the parameter String to the URL.

```
https://mydomain/script.php?code=33e3#f&0BOAA34&%
```

The PHP script cant work with the input parameter since it is not able to handle the special characters respectively misinterprets it.
If I echo $_GET['code'] I get

```
33e3
```

instead of

```
33e3#f&0BOAA34&%
```

How can I make the PHP script understand, that it shall accept the input string as a whole without interpreting the special characters. I already tried ' ' and " " here, without success.

Comment: try to use `POST` request instead of `GET` request

Comment: You need to [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the value before adding it to the URL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass text with special characters as get parameter in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212393/pass-text-with-special-characters-as-get-parameter-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode this string to url encoded format

```
33e3%23f%260BOAA34%26%25

https://mydomain/script.php?code=33e3%23f%260BOAA34%26%25
```

Answer (score 0):

Always Generate URL with encoded string

you can use [http_build_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

For example

```
$data = array(
    'foo' => '33e3#f&0BOAA34&%',
);

$domainName = "https://mydomain/script.php";

echo $domainName . "?" . http_build_query($data);
```

Which will return

```
https://mydomain/script.php?foo=33e3%23f%260BOAA34%26%25
```